# When the user logins in change the connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 application where I'll have several different databases. On user logon I want them to use their assigned database.

I have one master database that handles individual account logons, that will not change. Then I have the user databases, at the moment there is just one but in a few months time there could be 10 for example - all identical.

In my 'master' database, it holds the connection details for the user's assigned database. I'm struggling to find a way to amend the connection string to reflect that database.

The change/setting of the user database will happen after logon.

I've seen a lot of articles about swapping between existing database connection strings although these wouldn't work for me. I could be missing something obvious or another way of tackling this issue.

Comment: So you've got one context for the master database, and another for the user databases. When they log in you get their connection string from the master database and initialize the user database with that ..?

Comment: That's correct, I do. At present the application has 2x connection strings, one for the master and one for the user. Although the user string will change.

Comment: So if the user connection string is set at runtime from the value held in the master database, what do you mean by _"I'm struggling to find a way to amend the connection string to reflect that database"_?

Comment: No you're right, to use the phrase I couldn't see the wood for the trees is very apt here. Thank you for your help @stuartd your comments made me see I was been silly.